# Excel VBA Function update only on change

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a function that I have implemented as a VBA module which takes one cell as a parameter and queries a web services to return a result.  As the source of the data is remote, this function can take a few seconds to return.

The problem is that some actions, such as deleting any column, seem to cause every formula to recalculate, even if no change is needed.  When my sheet has several hundred rows, this can take several minutes during which time Excel is unresponsive.

I would like to find some way to detect that no change is needed and skip this step.  Some things I have tried:

- Determine the current value of the cell to be changed, from which I could determine if an update is needed.  But ActiveCell.Value is blank, and attempts to pass the cell itself as a second parameter are met with a circular reference warning.
- Created a second column to hold the old input value, which is then passed into the function and compared with the new value.  However, functions are not able to update this old value on success, and attempts to update with only formulas are always met with circular reference warnings.  Furthermore, it doesn't seem that a function can return a "no change", so I would need to store and use the old result.

Is there any way to prevent some actions from updating every formula on the sheet?

Other requirements:

- There may be a way to disable all formula automatic calculation, but I definitely want each row to update as soon as the parameter cell is entered.  I also don't want to force the user to push a button to update the function.
- I tried doing a custom spreadsheet in Visual Studio, but found the deployment too difficult to maintain for my user base.  Solution must be entirely contained in a macro-enabled workbook.
- Excel versions to use the sheet will be 2007 and 2010.

Comment: For a fixed input value, does the return value change over time, or will it be fixed?  If it will change, over what kind of timeframe?

Comment: You can use a worksheet_change event to capture changes in the input range, and populate the output cell(s) directly, without using a worksheet formula.

Comment: So you're saying that a function in module cannot update cells directly, but an overridden worksheet_change event on that specific sheet can?  Do I understand right?

Comment: Yes. Typically a function called from a worksheet can't change the sheet directly - it can only return a value. Although there are workarounds to this restriction I think they're probably best avoided. What's the best solution for your particular workbook will depend on other factors (eg. should the remote calls all update whenever the workbook is re-opened?, is the full remote dataset small enough you could cache the whole set locally?), but an event-based update might be a good approach.

Comment: No they should not be updated on form open, and yes the results are small enough to cache locally, which I am already doing.  Sounds like this will work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would

1. systematically block recalculation by setting File / Options / Formulas / Workbook Calculation to "Manual" and switch off "Recalculation on Save" as well
2. create a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and determine, under which conditions a recalculation should take place (`Target.Worksheet.Calculate`) - for example determine the coord's of the target (using `Target.Column` and `Target.Row`), and call the query from inside the Worksheet_Change trigger.
3. Eventually I would put the recalculation instruction in a Sub of its own and make a button into the sheet so the user can - on his/her wish - manually trigger recalculation (just in case the F9 key isn't known to the users)
4. It is also thinkable to use a global Boolean variable `need_Query` which is set by the Worksheet_Change trigger `If Target.Row = X And Target.Column = Y` (= the parameter) and have the query function examine (and reset) that Boolean, and go in the query only `If need_Query Then`, otherwise exit without action. Make sure that need_Query is set FALSE at worksheet load time, too.
5. Finally, you could convert the query function into a `Sub` and formulate some more complex conditions in the Worksheet_Change trigger to fire it (e.g. if a certain column changes, etc.).

Comment: Much of this seems copy-pasted from elsewhere as it either doesn't apply or goes against my stated requirements.  However, point 2 is the same as commented by Tim Williams, and because yours is the only reply done as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: copied and pasted probably from my own code base ... I am using all of the above where appropriate ... I really don't need to steal someone elses answers ... I am more interested in constructive discussions than in hooks and pluses ... wanted to show that moving the query froma function into a sub you have the full control when to fire it ... if there are more requirements or you want more detailed explanations, let's discuss

Comment: I wasn't accusing you of plagiarism.  I was only saying that Tim's answer was tailored to my specific problem, while yours is a bunch of tips that sometimes apply to me.  Specifically, Tim answered why Worksheet_Change works when a module function doesn't.  Still, your information is helpful and I have marked as an answer to my question.